# call shell class from controller

Tags: shell, cakephp, controller, cmd

I have a converterShell class and i need to call it from controller. the command will convert a video. when i tested from the cmd, it worked, but i need to call after my file is moved to the upload folder. I thought of put the "call" on a function and call when the filme is already moved. But the problem is to call the shell class. Here are the codes:

```
    class ConverterShell extends AppShell {
    public function main() {
        shell_exec('cd webroot\files\ && ffmpeg -i ' .fonte. 'whatever.wmv ' .destino. 'BLABLABLA.mp4');
    }
```

aaaand

```
    public function arquivos() {
        $this->autoRender = false;

        $name = $this->request->params['form']['upload']['name'];
        $type = $this->request->params['form']['upload']['type'];
        $tmp_name = $this->request->params['form']['upload']['tmp_name'];
        $error = $this->request->params['form']['upload']['error'];
        $size = $this->request->params['form']['upload']['size'];

        $path_parts = pathinfo($name);
        $formato = ($path_parts['extension']);
        $nome = ($path_parts['filename']);          

        $tamanho = ((($size)/1024)/1024);
        $tamanho_mb = number_format($tamanho, 2, '.', '');
        $string = $name;

        echo iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $string);
        if(!$error) {
            if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, WEBROOT_FOLDER . 'files/uploads/' . $name)) {
                $this->call function here();
                exit('OK!');
        } else {
            exit('Erro!');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should dismiss the thought of mixing console and application logic, they should be separated. Instead you could simply put the converter functionality in a [library class](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-folder-structure.html) and utilize that in your controller as well as in the shell.

Something like this (untested CakePHP 2.x example code):

**/app/lib/Converter.php**

```
class Converter {
    static public function convert($source, $destination) {
        $source = escapeshellarg(fonte . $source);
        $destination = escapeshellarg(destino . $destination);

        shell_exec('cd webroot\files\ && ffmpeg -i ' . $source . ' ' . $destination);
    }
}
```

**/app/Console/Command/ConverterShell.php**

```
App::uses('Converter', 'Lib');

class ConverterShell extends AppShell {
    public function main() {
        Converter::convert('whatever.wmv', 'BLABLABLA.mp4');
    }
}
```

**/app/Controller/WhateverController.php**

```
App::uses('Converter', 'Lib');

class WhateverController extends AppController {

    ...

    public function arquivos() {
        ...

        if(!$error) {
            if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, WEBROOT_FOLDER . 'files/uploads/' . $name)) {
                Converter::convert($name, $nome . '.mp4');
                exit('OK!');
            } else {
                exit('Erro!');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it doesnt work... with the code above when the file is moved to the folder, the command line should be executed and the conversion starts, right? when i tested from the cmd i typed "cake converter". this line has to be somewhere or not?

Comment: @B.Almeida Theoretically it should do that, yes, but remember that this is just example code to illustrate what I was suggesting! Also I can't help you with "_it doesn't work_", you'll have to show your debugging results and actually describe the problem you are experiencing.

Comment: the debug doesnt show any error, the file is correctly moved to the right folder, the command line is correct, but the conversion just not happen

Comment: well, for now im just gonna call an external php file to run the conversion... (: thank you!